# SVG not filling out like fontawesome icons like it has padding or whitespace

Tags: svg, vector, adobe-illustrator, react-native-svg

Can anyone tell me why this custom SVG on the right won't fill the height like the icon on the right does? The SVG does not have any space on the top and right when opened in Illustrator.

[image]

**Current SVG markup**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 27.9.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         viewBox="0 0 720 720" enable-background="new 0 0 720 720" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
        <path d="M372.7,463.4c7.7-12.1,13-24.8,16-38.3c3.1-14.9,2.9-29.2-0.4-42.7c-3.4-13.5-9.3-25.2-17.8-34.9
            c8-7.5,14.7-16.1,20.2-25.6s9.5-19.9,12-30.9c2.8-13.3,2.9-25.8,0.3-37.4s-7.3-21.7-14.1-30.4c-6.8-8.7-15.5-15.5-25.9-20.4
            c-10.5-5-22.3-7.4-35.3-7.4H187.1c-3.1,0-5.7,0.9-7.8,2.8c-2.1,1.9-3.5,4.3-4.2,7.4l-65.7,309.7c-0.7,3.3-0.4,5.7,1.1,7.2
            c1.5,1.6,3.7,2.3,6.7,2.3h153.7c13,0,26-2.7,38.8-8c12.9-5.3,24.7-12.5,35.4-21.6S365,475.4,372.7,463.4z M301.3,421.8
            c-1,4.7-2.9,9.3-5.5,13.8c-2.7,4.4-5.9,8.4-9.7,11.9c-3.8,3.5-8,6.2-12.5,8.3c-4.6,2.1-9.3,3.1-14.2,3.1h-51.9l15.8-74.1h51.9
            c4.9,0,9.2,1.1,12.9,3.3c3.7,2.2,6.7,5.1,9,8.5c2.3,3.5,3.8,7.4,4.5,11.9C302.2,412.9,302.2,417.3,301.3,421.8z M317,292.9
            c-1,4.7-2.8,9.1-5.3,13s-5.6,7.3-9.2,10.2c-3.6,2.9-7.7,5.1-12.2,6.7s-9.3,2.3-14.3,2.3h-40.2l13.5-64.3h40.8c4.9,0,9.2,0.9,13,2.6
            s6.8,4,9.2,7c2.4,3,4,6.4,4.8,10.2C317.9,284.3,317.9,288.5,317,292.9z"/>
        <path d="M607.4,366.1H402c1.4,3.9,2.7,7.8,3.7,11.9c4.1,16.2,4.3,33.2,0.6,50.8v0.2c-3.4,15.4-9.6,30.3-18.4,44.1
            c-8.6,13.5-19.1,25.6-31.2,35.8c-7.1,6-14.7,11.3-22.6,15.9h240.3c6.6,0,13.3-6,14.8-13.4l27.4-131.9
            C618.2,372.1,614,366.1,607.4,366.1z M479.6,425.4l-2.5,11.9c-0.3,1.3-0.9,2.4-1.9,3.3s-2.2,1.4-3.5,1.4H461l-11,51.3
            c-0.6,2.6-2.2,3.9-5,3.9h-18c-2.7,0-3.8-1.3-3.2-3.9l11-51.3H424c-3,0-4.2-1.5-3.5-4.6l2.5-11.9c0.6-2.9,2.4-4.4,5.4-4.4h10.7
            l4.1-19.3c0.3-1,0.8-1.9,1.6-2.7c0.8-0.8,1.9-1.3,3.3-1.6l19.5-3c1,0,1.8,0.3,2.2,1c0.5,0.7,0.6,1.6,0.3,2.7l-4.9,22.8h10.7
            c1.3,0,2.2,0.4,2.9,1.1C479.7,422.8,479.9,423.9,479.6,425.4z M572.8,425.3c-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.6c-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.6
            l-40.1,64.7c-0.4,0.6-0.7,1.3-1.2,1.9c-0.4,0.7-0.9,1.3-1.4,1.9s-1.1,1.1-1.8,1.5s-1.4,0.6-2.2,0.6h-18.3c-1,0-1.7-0.1-2.1-0.4
            c-0.5-0.3-0.8-0.7-1.1-1.2c-0.3-0.7-0.5-1.4-0.7-2.1s-0.4-1.5-0.5-2.2c-1.9-10.7-4-21.4-6.1-32.1s-4.2-21.4-6.1-32.1
            c-0.1,0-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.7c0-0.4,0-0.8,0.2-1.2c0.4-1.8,1.7-2.7,3.9-2.7h21.8c1.2,0,2.1,0.3,2.7,0.9c0.6,0.6,1,1.4,1.1,2.5
            c0.2,3,0.5,6.4,0.8,10s0.6,7.2,1,10.8c0.3,3.6,0.6,6.9,0.8,10c0.3,3.1,0.4,5.7,0.5,7.6l19.5-38.6c0.7-1.2,1.5-2,2.3-2.5
            s1.8-0.8,3-0.8h21.4c1.4,0,2.3,0.3,2.7,0.8C572.9,423.7,573,424.4,572.8,425.3z"/>
    </g>
    </svg>
```

adding viewBox="109 195 510 330" and enabled background got me this now. Its off in position but size looks right.

[image]

Comment: You would need a different viewBox value for the svg element. Please try  `viewBox="109 195 510 330"`

Comment: Can you explain why you are using those numbers and how you got them?

Comment: It's the bounding box of the group wrapping both path elements. You can get the bounding box of an svg element by using the getBBox() method. In order to understand what happens put a border around the svg element before and after changing the viewBox value. Also do not forget to change the enable-background to the same value or delete it altogether.

Comment: I updated the question, it enalrged right, but position is now off. Here is the full URL https://cdn.exposureevents.com/content/images/site/icons/ballertv.svg

Comment: Shouldnt I do 0 0 510 330?

Comment: As I've commented above: _Please try viewBox="109 195 510 330"_

Comment: I did, it got me that second display you see in the question

Comment: Why was 109 and 195 chosen? All font awesome SVG look to be 0 and 0 with height of 512 but variable widths.

Comment: As I've commented above: _It's the bounding box of the group wrapping both path elements.  You can get the bounding box of an svg element by using the getBBox() method_

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it work with downloading a similar size viewbox SVG from font awesome.  Opened it in illustrator, removed the current FA icon and pasted this one in and made sure it worked to FA standards and it worked!

[image]

```html
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 640 512"><!--!Font Awesome Pro 6.5.1 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license (Commercial License) Copyright 2024 Fonticons, Inc.--><path d="M332.2 386.7c9.7-15.2 16.4-31.3 20.2-48.3c3.9-18.8 3.7-36.8-.5-53.8c-4.3-17-11.7-31.8-22.4-44c10.1-9.5 18.5-20.3 25.5-32.3c6.9-12 12-25.1 15.1-38.9c3.5-16.8 3.7-32.5 .4-47.1s-9.2-27.3-17.8-38.3s-19.5-19.5-32.6-25.7C306.8 52 291.9 49 275.5 49H98.4c-3.9 0-7.2 1.1-9.8 3.5s-4.4 5.4-5.3 9.3L.5 452.1c-.9 4.2-.5 7.2 1.4 9.1c1.9 2 4.7 2.9 8.4 2.9H204c16.4 0 32.8-3.4 48.9-10.1c16.3-6.7 31.1-15.8 44.6-27.2c13.4-11.5 25-25 34.7-40.1zm-89.9-52.4c-1.3 5.9-3.7 11.7-6.9 17.4c-3.4 5.5-7.4 10.6-12.2 15s-10.1 7.8-15.8 10.5c-5.8 2.6-11.7 3.9-17.9 3.9h-65.4l19.9-93.4h65.4c6.2 0 11.6 1.4 16.3 4.2s8.4 6.4 11.3 10.7c2.9 4.4 4.8 9.3 5.7 15c.7 5.5 .7 11-.4 16.7zM262 171.9c-1.3 5.9-3.5 11.5-6.7 16.4s-7.1 9.2-11.6 12.9s-9.7 6.4-15.4 8.4s-11.7 2.9-18 2.9h-50.7l17-81H228c6.2 0 11.6 1.1 16.4 3.3c4.8 2.1 8.6 5 11.6 8.8s5 8.1 6 12.9c1.2 4.5 1.2 9.8 0 15.4zm366 92.2H369.2c1.8 4.9 3.4 9.8 4.7 15c5.2 20.4 5.4 41.8 .8 64v.3c-4.3 19.4-12.1 38.2-23.2 55.6c-10.8 17-24.1 32.3-39.3 45.1c-8.9 7.6-18.5 14.2-28.5 20h302.8c8.3 0 16.8-7.6 18.6-16.9L639.6 281c2-9.3-3.3-16.9-11.6-16.9zM466.9 338.8l-3.2 15c-.4 1.6-1.1 3-2.4 4.2c-1.3 1.1-2.8 1.8-4.4 1.8h-13.5l-13.9 64.6c-.8 3.3-2.8 4.9-6.3 4.9h-22.7c-3.4 0-4.8-1.6-4-4.9l13.9-64.6h-13.6c-3.8 0-5.3-1.9-4.4-5.8l3.2-15c.8-3.7 3-5.5 6.8-5.5h13.5l5.2-24.3c.4-1.3 1-2.4 2-3.4s2.4-1.6 4.2-2l24.6-3.8c1.3 0 2.3 .4 2.8 1.3c.6 .9 .8 2 .4 3.4l-6.2 28.7h13.5c1.6 0 2.8 .5 3.7 1.4c1 .7 1.2 2.1 .8 4zm117.5-.1c-.1 .3-.1 .5-.3 .8c-.1 .3-.1 .5-.3 .8l-50.5 81.5c-.5 .8-.9 1.6-1.5 2.4c-.5 .9-1.1 1.6-1.8 2.4c-.6 .8-1.4 1.4-2.3 1.9s-1.8 .8-2.8 .8H502c-1.3 0-2.1-.1-2.6-.5c-.6-.4-1-.9-1.4-1.5c-.4-.9-.6-1.8-.9-2.6s-.5-1.9-.6-2.8c-2.4-13.5-5-27-7.7-40.4c-2.6-13.5-5.3-27-7.7-40.4c-.1 0-.1-.4-.1-.9s0-1 .3-1.5c.5-2.3 2.1-3.4 4.9-3.4h27.5c1.5 0 2.6 .4 3.4 1.1c.8 .8 1.3 1.8 1.4 3.2c.3 3.8 .6 8.1 1 12.6s.8 9.1 1.3 13.6c.4 4.5 .8 8.7 1 12.6c.4 3.9 .5 7.2 .6 9.6l24.6-48.6c.9-1.5 1.9-2.5 2.9-3.2c1-.6 2.3-1 3.8-1h27c1.8 0 2.9 .4 3.4 1c.4 .5 .5 1.4 .3 2.5z"/></svg>
```